# Elastic search dynamic field mapping with range query on price field

Tags: elasticsearch, range, elasticsearch-aggregation, solr-boost, dynamic-mapping

I have two fields in my elastic search which is **lowest_local_price** and **lowest_global_price**.

I want to map dynamic value to third field **price** on run time *based on local or global country*.

If local country matched then i want to map lowest_local_price value to price field.

If global country matched then i want to map lowest_global_price value to price field.

If local or global country matched then **i want to apply range query on the price field and boost that doc by 2.0**.

Note : This is not compulsary filter or query, if matched then just want to boost the doc.

I have tried below solution but does not work for me.

Query 1:

```
$params["body"] = [
            "runtime_mappings" => [
                "price" => [
                    "type" => "double",
                    "script" => [
                        "source" => "if (params['_source']['country_en_name'] == '$country_name' ) { emit(params['_source']['lowest_local_price']); } else { emit( params['_source']['global_rates']['$country->id']['lowest_global_price']); }"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "query" => [
                "bool" => [
                    "filter" => [
                        "range" => [ "price" => [ "gte" => $min_price]]
                    ],
                    "boost" => 2.0
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Query 2:

```
$params["body"] = [
            "runtime_mappings" => [
                "price" => [
                    "type" => "double",
                    "script" => [
                        "source" => "if (params['_source']['country_en_name'] == '$country_name' ) { emit(params['_source']['lowest_local_price']); } else { emit( params['_source']['global_rates']['$country->id']['lowest_global_price']); }"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "query" => [
                "bool" => [
                    "filter" => [
                        "range" => [ "price" => [ "gte" => $min_price, "boost" => 2.0]]
                    ],
                    
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

None of them working for me, because it can boost the doc. I know filter does not work with boost, then what is the solution for **dynamic field mapping with range query and boost**?

Please help me to solve this query.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem? If not, would you like to try out the approach I suggested and tell me if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can (most likely) achieve what you want without [`runtime_mappings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/runtime-mapping-fields.html) by using a combination of [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-bool-query.html) queries, here's how.

### Let's define test mapping

We need to clarify what mapping we are working with, because different field types require different query types.

Let's assume that your mapping looks like this:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "runtime",
    "properties": {
      "country_en_name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lowest_local_price": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "global_rates": {
        "properties": {
          "UK": {
            "properties":{
              "lowest_global_price": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "FR": {
            "properties":{
              "lowest_global_price": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "US": {
            "properties":{
              "lowest_global_price": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `country_en_name` is of type [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/text.html), in general such fields should be indexed as [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/keyword.html) but for the sake of demonstration of the use of `runtime_mappings` I kept it `text` and will show later how to overcome this limitation.

### [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-bool-query.html) is the same as `if` for Elasticsearch

The query without runtime mappings might look like this:

```
POST my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "country_en_name": "UK"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "lowest_local_price": {
                          "gte": 1000
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "global_rates.UK.lowest_global_price": {
                    "gte": 1000
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This can be interpreted as the following:

```
Any document
OR (
  (document with country_en_name=UK AND lowest_local_price > X)
  OR
  (document with global_rates.UK.lowest_global_price > X)
)[boost this part of OR]
```

The [`match_all`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) is needed to return also documents that do not match the other queries.

### How will the response of the query look like?

Let's put some documents in the ES:

```
POST my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "country_en_name": "UK",
  "lowest_local_price": 1500,
  "global_rates": {
    "FR": {
      "lowest_global_price": 1000
    },
    "US": {
      "lowest_global_price": 1200
    }
  }
}

POST my-index-000001/_doc/2
{
  "country_en_name": "FR",
  "lowest_local_price": 900,
  "global_rates": {
    "UK": {
      "lowest_global_price": 950
    },
    "US": {
      "lowest_global_price": 1500
    }
  }
}

POST my-index-000001/_doc/3
{
  "country_en_name": "US",
  "lowest_local_price": 950,
  "global_rates": {
    "UK": {
      "lowest_global_price": 1100
    },
    "FR": {
      "lowest_global_price": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

Now the result of the search query above will be something like:

```
{
...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 4.9616585,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 4.9616585,
        "_source" : {
          "country_en_name" : "UK",
          "lowest_local_price" : 1500,
          ...
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country_en_name" : "US",
          "lowest_local_price" : 950,
          "global_rates" : {
            "UK" : {
              "lowest_global_price" : 1100
            },
            ...
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country_en_name" : "FR",
          "lowest_local_price" : 900,
          "global_rates" : {
            "UK" : {
              "lowest_global_price" : 950
            },
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that document with `_id:2` is on the bottom because it didn't match any of the boosted queries.

### Will `runtime_mappings` be of any use?

Runtime mappings are useful in case there's an existing mapping with data types that do not permit to execute a certain type of query. In previous versions (before 7.11) one would have to do a reindex in such cases, but now it is possible to use runtime mappings (but the query is more expensive).

In our case, we have got `country_en_name` indexed as `text` which is suited for full-text search and not for exact lookups. We should rather use `keyword` instead. This is how the query may look like with the help of `runtime_mappings`:

```
POST my-index-000001/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "country_en_name_keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(params['_source']['country_en_name'])"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "country_en_name_keyword": "UK"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "lowest_local_price": {
                          "gte": 1000
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "global_rates.UK.lowest_global_price": {
                    "gte": 1000
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how we created a new runtime field `country_en_name_keyword` with type `keyword` and used a [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-term-query.html) lookup instead of [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-match-query.html) query.

Comment: My visibility booster structure is like below

"visibility_boosters":
[
 {
  "booster_rate": 20,
  "id": 20,
  "country_id": 2
 },
 {
  "booster_rate": 10,
  "id": 19,
  "country_id": 1
 }
]

Comment: And global rates structure is like below :

"global_rates": {
 "Bhutan": 200,
 "Australia": 200
}

Comment: @KajalPandya so you basically have country ID on local level, and country name for "global", right? Do you have both of them at query time?